# Update DOM on item drag/drop w/jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

I have a table with two columns. Each column has a unique ID "pick" and "drop". Also i have a number of items in the first column. Using jQuery UI draggable/droppable I drag the items from the first column (pick) into the second one (drop).

I need to update the DOM when the item is moved, remove the item from "pick" and add it to "drop". I need help putting it all into a function. The function will be included into a part of code where I can detect drop.

Answer (score 6):

here is how i did this, it will change the parent of the dropped element to the element it was dropped onto.

```
$( ".droppable" ).droppable({   
    drop: function( event, ui ) {
        $(ui.draggable).appendTo($( this ));
}});
```

and here is how i would edit it so it doesnt run if it does not need to

```
$( ".droppable" ).droppable({   
    drop: function( event, ui ) {
        if($(ui.draggable).parent() !==$(this)){
            $(ui.draggable).appendTo($( this ));
        }
}});
```

after thinking on your new problem i think you should try this. for this to work, the `drop` column needs to have a `top` and a `left` with `position:absolute` and the main wrapper that contains both columns needs to be `position:relative`

```
$( ".droppable" ).droppable({   
    drop: function( event, ui ) {
        var $kid = $(ui.draggable);
        var $dad = $(this);
        if($kid.parent() !== $dad)){
            $kid.appendTo($dad);
            $kid.css('left', $kid.left() - $dad.left());
            $kid.css('top', $kid.top() - $dad.top());

        }
}});
```

Comment: This is brilliant --  a lot simpler than I was thinking. So i don't really need to do .remove()?

Comment: I think I need to modify the code to have a specific ID instead of .parent(). In my case there are other children withing that "drop" area and while I move the item within one of them everything is OK, but as soon as it leaves that child, while still within "drop" the items disappears...

Comment: Also, I noticed that when I use $(ui.draggable).appendTo($( this ));
on drop the item jumps and does not remain in the place where it was dropped...

Comment: well. it would seem that the problem is withen your css. it looks like a problem with 'top' and 'left'. be sure to set the `drop` element to `position:relative`, if it is already set to that, remove it, and set the entire wrapper to `position:relative;`and i think that will fix your problem.

Comment: after playing more with it, it is definitely a css issue having to do with top and left. play with it, and if u cant get it. post some code and css and i can play with it here

Comment: Hmm, I think this is the right direction. It is possibly that my layout is getting in a way The entire "cork" are is a table, with id #grid and the 4 squares each have .class but each also has its own ID. So I guess I need to target #grid(num) .grid. I have added position:relative; to .grid but it seems I broke something...

Comment: The behavior I am trying to achieve is like http://www.usabilitest.com/uxowBCc and the only difference I need for the items to slide up to fill the gap of the cards removed from the left.

Comment: its really hard to say without having all of the code to play around with. after re-reading my example though, i think that the `drop` column should ALSO have `position:relative` instead of `position:absolute`.  i am positive your problem is css `top` and `left` placement after changing parents. the dropped item is getting its `top` and `left` in relation to the entire wrapper but when it has a new parent, it kicks the dropped item to far to the right, sometimes out of the screen. so u need to subtract the `top` and `left` of the drop column in the css of the dropped item to reposition it.